# Loop with table names in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I have three dataframes:

`AAA_PROSTATEx`, `BBB_PROSTATEx`, `CCC_PROSTATEx`,

and I want to process and create the dataframes as followed, but I don't know how to use loops to solve them. Ideally, there will be two loops:

```
### loop #1 ####
AAA_PROSTATEx_1 <- AAA_PROSTATEx[48:57, ]
BBB_PROSTATEx_1 <- BBB_PROSTATEx[48:57, ]
CCC_PROSTATEx_1 <- CCC_PROSTATEx[48:57, ]

# **name**_PROSTATEx_1 <- *name**_PROSTATEx[48:57, ]



### loop #2 ###
AAA_PROSTATEx_1  <-                                                   
  AAA_PROSTATEx_1 %>%
  mutate(V2.T2.Total = select(., V2.T2.Artef:V2.T2.Sag) %>%
           rowSums()
  )

BBB_PROSTATEx_1  <-                                                   
  BBB_PROSTATEx_1 %>%
  mutate(V2.T2.Total = select(., V2.T2.Artef:V2.T2.Sag) %>%
           rowSums()
  )


CCC_PROSTATEx_1  <-                                                   
  CCC_PROSTATEx_1 %>%
  mutate(V2.T2.Total = select(., V2.T2.Artef:V2.T2.Sag) %>%
           rowSums()
  )



# **name**_PROSTATEx_1  <-                                                  
  **name**_PROSTATEx_1 %>%
  mutate(V2.T2.Total = select(., V2.T2.Artef:V2.T2.Sag) %>%
           rowSums()
  )
```

Comment: Do you need to store the data.frames in separate variables? Alternatively you could create a list of these data.frames and loop through the list. Probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assign` and `get` to refer a variable by character name

```
tables <- c("AAA_PROSTATEx", "BBB_PROSTATEx", "CCC_PROSTATEx")
new_tables <- paste0(tables, "_1")

### loop #1 ####
for(i in seq_along(tables)){
    assign(new_tables[i], get(tables[i])[48:57, ])
}

# **name**_PROSTATEx_1 <- *name**_PROSTATEx[48:57, ]

### loop #2 ###
for(i in seq_along(tables)){
    assign(new_tables[i], get(new_tables[i]) %>%
      mutate(V2.T2.Total = select(., V2.T2.Artef:V2.T2.Sag) %>%
               rowSums()
      ))
}
```

However, as @tacoman suggests, it would be better to work with a list of dataframes instead

Comment: If the answer solved you problem please vote it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It almost solved my probelm. However, my orinignal dataset are AAA_PROSTATEx, BBB_PROSTATEx, and CCC_PROSTATEx. By following these lines, I would update AAA_PROSTATEx, BBB_PROSTATEx, and CCC_PROSTATEx, rather than create new tables AAA_PROSTATEx_1, BBB_PROSTATE_1. How to create new dataframe instead of updating existed dataframe?

Comment: I modified the original post to create new dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple:

```
library(dplyr)
tables <- list(AAA_PROSTATEx, BBB_PROSTATEx, CCC_PROSTATEx)

lapply(tables, function(x) {
  x %>%
    dplyr::filter(dplyr::row_number() %in% 48:57) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(V2.T2.Total = dplyr::select(.,V2.T2.Artef:V2.T2.Sag) %>%
           rowSums())
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I got "Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character". By the way, my original data are dataframes, not tables, not sure if it caused the error.